# Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64) for linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu-16.04

Good day,

Hello is it possible to install Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64) in ubuntu server? ive tried to follow steps below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu

but the procedure install to 2017 version (14.xx.xx.x)

we have existing License for this and we want to it to used under Ubuntu 16.04LTS Server

Any help and suggestion is **HIGHLY APPRECIATED :D**

Regards,

TIA

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2016 for ubuntu

Comment: Hi sir can we have a reference link for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No ,you can't..

SQL2017 is the first cross platform version of SQLSERVER.Below is a link from [SQLskills](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/operating-system-support-for-sql-server-versions/) showing sql on supported Os

[image]